# cannot resolve setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment

Tags: android, fingerprint

I'm creating an app that can use fingerprint authentication on devices having fingerprint sensor using `FingerprintManager`. I'm following google API Guides available  [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html):

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.goyal.fingerprinttest"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled false
        } 
    }
}

dependencies {
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"
compile "com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1"
compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1"
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1"
}
```

Comment: Share your gradle file

Comment: dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:24.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1"
}

Comment: ^Use the 'edit' button towards the bottom-left of your post to add more relevant inform regarding your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself

actually setInvalidatedByBiometricEnrollment is only visible on API level +24.

Just need to set compileSdkVersion to 24

Comment: Yeah...I just came back to comment that...but, you found it already!